# Problemas para copilar codigo, pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyinstaller

tudo bem?  Eu estou travado 100% com um programa que estou fazendo que não funciona de nenhuma forma apos eu copilar, sempre é apresentado esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o programa funciona normalmente pelo VisualStudioCode ou o Pycharm, só sempre da erro na hora de copilar, eu ja fiz diversars coisas diferentes, ja mudei versões das lib, ja alterei a estrutura do codigo, ja mudei as versões do pyinstaller, ja tentei adicionar os modulos das lib manualmente, mas nadaaa funciona, sempre da erro, as lib que estou usando dentro do codigo são: playwright, os, PyAutoGUI e PySimpleGUI;

Será que um anjo de Deus ja passou por isso e consegue me ajudar???

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Para o pessoal que passou por esse problema, uma maneira que consegui resolver foi desatualizando a versão do greenlet para 1.1.3 e também modifiquei uma linha do meu codigo onde está o playwright:

```
    self.brow = self.p.chromium.launch(headless=False, executable_path=r'files\chrome-win\chrome.exe')
```

eu adicionei esse executable_path, que teve a função de localizar o navegador que será executado, depois disso deu tudo certo.